# Making n-length sublists for every item within reach of an index

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have a list `l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']` and a given element `e = 'b'` and I want to make 3-length sublists off of elements no further than `3` positions away from our element, including the element. We would want to produce the following result for our example:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'd']]
```

As you can see it can't go further left because the element's position is smaller than the reach, and it goes as far as the element `'d'` (index `4`) on the right.

This is my native solution:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
n = len(l)
reach = 3
e = 'b'
idx = l.index(e)
result = []
for i in range(reach):
  lb, rb = idx - i, idx - i + reach
  if lb >= 0:
    result.append(l[lb:rb])
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it, e.g. with `itertools` or `zip`?

Comment: @superbrain changed it to letters

Comment: If you change `reach` to 2 or 4, the result doesn't look right...

Comment: Or if you use `e = 'g'` (with reach=3), it also doesn't look right.

Comment: @superbrain right, fixed it

Comment: So for `reach = 1` you want an empty result?

Answer (score 0):

I'd compute the min/max starting index for the sublists instead of going too far (and filtering) or not going far enough (and missing something!):

```
idx = l.index(e)
min_start = max(idx - reach + 1, 0)
max_start = min(idx, n - reach)
result = [l[i:i+reach] for i in range(min_start, max_start + 1)]
```